# Piecewise to Heaviside

Tags: laplace-transform, piecewise-continuity

I really need help with this exercise, I try by days.
Use Heaviside in this exercise:
$$f(t) = \begin{cases} 2t^2 + 4t +1 ,& 0 \leq t < 6 \\4t^2 -16t+50 ,& t \geq 6\end{cases}$$
for show L{f(t)} = $\dfrac{(s+2)^2}{s^3} + \dfrac{e^{-6s} (s+2)^2}{s^3}$

My solution:
$f(t)$ = $2t^{2} + 4t +1 + [4t^2 -16t+50$ $-(2t^2 + 4t +1)]H(t-6)$

$2t^2 + 4t +1$ + $[2t^2 -20t +49]$ H(t-6)

$2t^2 + 4t +1$ + $[2(t-6)^2 +4(t-6)+1]$ H(t-6)

In the last step I used partial\
$[2t^2 -20t +49]  = A(t-6)^2 + B(t-6)+C$

Comment: Oh thanks, I wrong in a minus

Comment: So semi-translating back the claim is that $f(t)=(D+2)^2(t_+^2+(t-6)_+^2)/2$ where $(t-c)_+=\max(0,t-c)=(t-c)H(t-c)$.